# How can I save and restore AlloyUI FormBuilder fields?

Tags: javascript, alloy-ui

I want to save the user selected and predefined fields of an AlloyUI `FormBuilder`. I have tried to use `JSON.stringify(formBuilder.get('fields'))`, but I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
```

How can I save (and restore) the fields of an AlloyUI `FormBuilder`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to save the fields of an AlloyUI `FormBuilder`, you can use [`field.getAttributesForCloning()`](http://alloyui.com/api/classes/A.FormBuilderField.html#method_getAttributesForCloning) to obtain the important field attributes. Then you can combine those attributes into an array. Finally, you can convert the array to JSON to save it with `JSON.stringify()`:

```
var fields = [];
formBuilder.get('fields').each(function(field) {
    fields.push(field.getAttributesForCloning());
});
fields = JSON.stringify(fields);
```

If you want to restore the fields, you can use `JSON.parse()` on the JSON:

```
new Y.FormBuilder({
    /* ...your code here... */
    fields: JSON.parse(fields)
}).render();
```

Here's a runnable example using [AlloyUI's example `FormBuilder` code](http://alloyui.com/examples/form-builder/):

```js
YUI().use('aui-form-builder', function(Y) {
  var formBuilder = new Y.FormBuilder({
    availableFields: [{
      iconClass: 'form-builder-field-icon-text',
      id: 'uniqueTextField',
      label: 'Text',
      readOnlyAttributes: ['name'],
      type: 'text',
      unique: true,
      width: 75
    }, {
      hiddenAttributes: ['tip'],
      iconClass: 'form-builder-field-icon-textarea',
      label: 'Textarea',
      type: 'textarea'
    }, {
      iconClass: 'form-builder-field-icon-checkbox',
      label: 'Checkbox',
      type: 'checkbox'
    }, {
      iconClass: 'form-builder-field-icon-button',
      label: 'Button',
      type: 'button'
    }, {
      iconClass: 'form-builder-field-icon-select',
      label: 'Select',
      type: 'select'
    }, {
      iconClass: 'form-builder-field-icon-radio',
      label: 'Radio Buttons',
      type: 'radio'
    }, {
      iconClass: 'form-builder-field-icon-fileupload',
      label: 'File Upload',
      type: 'fileupload'
    }, {
      iconClass: 'form-builder-field-icon-fieldset',
      label: 'Fieldset',
      type: 'fieldset'
    }],
    boundingBox: '#myFormBuilder',
    fields: [{
      label: 'City',
      options: [{
        label: 'Ney York',
        value: 'new york'
      }, {
        label: 'Chicago',
        value: 'chicago'
      }],
      predefinedValue: 'chicago',
      type: 'select'
    }, {
      label: 'Colors',
      options: [{
        label: 'Red',
        value: 'red'
      }, {
        label: 'Green',
        value: 'green'
      }, {
        label: 'Blue',
        value: 'blue'
      }],
      type: 'radio'
    }]
  }).render();

  Y.one('#resetFormBuilder').on('click', function(event) {
    var fields = [];
    formBuilder.get('fields').each(function(field) {
      fields.push(field.getAttributesForCloning());
    });
    fields = JSON.stringify(fields);
    formBuilder.destroy();
    event.target.set('style', 'display: none;');
    new Y.FormBuilder({
      /* ...your code here... */
      boundingBox: '#myFormBuilder',
      fields: JSON.parse(fields)
    }).render();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="http://cdn.alloyui.com/3.0.1/aui/aui-min.js"></script>
<link href="http://cdn.alloyui.com/3.0.1/aui-css/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"></link>
<div class="yui3-skin-sam">
  <button id="resetFormBuilder" class="btn btn-primary">
    Reset <code>FormBuilder</code>
  </button>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="myFormBuilder"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you please tell me how can I get "Json data" of created form using alloyui form builder.

Comment: @SanjayGohil, not sure what you are asking. Seems like this answer explains how to get the JSON data of the AlloyUI form builer.

Comment: I have add AlloyUI form builer in my website admin side and add new field using drag and drop  now I want to save this form in my database with same field structure and render in front end. See this screenshot : https://www.screencast.com/t/bhIQuvQrj

Comment: @SanjayGohil, create a new question with an [mcve] that explains why this answer doesn't work.